# GHC optimizes allocations away

Tags: haskell, ghc

I'm trying to improve performance of [this binary-trees benchmark](http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u64q/program.php?test=binarytrees&lang=ghc&id=5) from [The Computer Language Benchmark Game](http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u64q/haskell.html). The idea is to build lots of binary trees to benchmark memory allocation. The Tree data definition looks like this:

```
data Tree = Nil | Node !Int !Tree !Tree
```

According to the problem statement, there's no need to store an `Int` in every node and other languages [don't have it](http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u64q/program.php?test=binarytrees&lang=ocaml&id=2).

I use GHC 8.2.2 and get the following RTS report when run the original code:

```
stack --resolver lts-10.3 --compiler ghc-8.2.2 ghc -- --make -O2 -threaded -rtsopts -funbox-strict-fields -XBangPatterns -fllvm -pgmlo opt-3.9 -pgmlc llc-3.9 binarytrees.hs -o binarytrees.ghc_run
./binarytrees.ghc_run +RTS -N4 -sstderr -K128M -H  -RTS 21
...
      19,551,302,672 bytes allocated in the heap
       7,291,702,272 bytes copied during GC
         255,946,744 bytes maximum residency (18 sample(s))
             233,480 bytes maximum slop
         635 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)
...
Total   time   58.620s  ( 39.281s elapsed)
```

So far so good. Let's remove this Int, which is actually never used. The definition becomes

```
data Tree = Nil | Node !Tree !Tree
```

In theory we are going to save about 25% of total memory (3 integers in every node instead of 4). Let's try it:

```
 ...
 313,388,960 bytes allocated in the heap
     640,488 bytes copied during GC
      90,016 bytes maximum residency (2 sample(s))
      57,872 bytes maximum slop
           5 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)
 ...
 Total   time    9.596s  (  9.621s elapsed)
```

5MB total memory in use and almost zero GC? Why? Where did all the allocations go?

Comment: How have you amended the `make` function to fit the new type? Removed its first parameter; left the parameter in but never use it; or something else?

Comment: Yes, I have just removed the first parameter.

Comment: Are you sure you are actually creating the trees? Maybe laziness kicked in and removed *all* of your computations.

Comment: Well, the program outputs the correct result, and the tree slots are marked as strict. If I make them lazy, the program actually becomes significantly slower and allocates much more memory (the "total memory in use" is still low though).

Comment: It seems likely you are benefitting from the same or similar optimization that makes static allocations for enumerations and just points to the (shared, static) value for any given nullary constructor.

Comment: Having looked at the code, I think you've found one of the rare points where GHC will do common subexpression elimination on non-primitive types, and it pays off.  You're using linear space in the size of a tree instead of exponential, because `make` uses the same child element for both sides.  This benchmark looks like it was designed explicitly to punish purity and optimization.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the sudden memory usage drop caused by the [Common Sub-expression Elimination](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC_optimisations#Common_subexpression_elimination) optimization. The original code was:

```
make i d = Node i (make d d2) (make d2 d2)
--                      ^           ^
--                      |           d2 != d
--                      d != d2
```

Since expressions constructing the left and the right subtrees are different, the compiler is not able eliminate any allocations.

If I remove the unused integer, the code looks like this

```
make d = Node (make (d - 1)) (make (d - 1))
--            ^              ^
--            |              |
--            `--------------`----- identical
```

If I add the `-fno-cse` flag to GHC, the memory allocation is as high as expected, but the code is rather slow. I couldn't find a way to suppress this optimization locally so I decided to "outsmart" the compiler by adding extra unused arguments:

```
make' :: Int -> Int -> Tree
make' _  0 = Node Nil Nil
make' !n d = Node (make' (n - 1) (d - 1)) (make' (n + 1) (d - 1))
```

The trick worked, the memory usage dropped by expected 30%. But I wish there was a nicer way to tell the compiler what I want.

Thanks to @Carl for mentioning the CSE optimization.

Comment: The way to know for sure if you're seeing CSE would be to look at the optimised Core. Compile with `-ddump-simpl` to get at it